# jQuery .dialog() + .post() problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form on modal dialog that need to be filled up and on pressing "Save" save results into database. I use following code to open form which is jQuery-ui dialog and jQuery .post() method. I don't need to show anything when form is closed and processed.

```
    $('#cdialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
                $.post('process.php', $("#cform").serialize());
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
        Cancel: function() {                    
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
$('#cdialog').dialog('open');
```

This is code in process.php

```
$data = (object)array(
    'map' => $_POST['map'],
    'type' => $_POST['type'],
    'name' => $_POST['name']
);

Concepts::save($data);
```

I checked with `alert($("#testform").serialize())` in "Save" function that parameters are actually being passed. Checked with Apache log that POST request is being sent. But it is still not working. If I just run php file passing all parametes in array without trying to get $_POST variables, data is saved. I don't understand why it is not working from dialog...

Comment: @Jull - Can you paste the output from Apache?  What about if you print out the contents of the PHP array?

Comment: Apache output 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2011:15:33:21 +1300] "POST /concept/process.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3472
I was trying to print out array using print_r($data), but with no luck. It seems like process.php is not accessed at all...

Comment: Is it normal to cast an array to an object?  What do you get in your print/echo statement if you just assign the array directly to data?

Comment: I don't think it matters. In this case it would print out "Array ( [map] => 34 [type] => 1 [name] => test)" instead "stdClass Object ( [map] => 34 [type] => 1 [name] => test )". The problem is that it is not printing anything at all. No response from php file no matter if I try to print_r or echo. It is being accessed and parameters are passed, it's just not doing anything. I completely lost...

Comment: Would you mind changing ` $.post('process.php', $("#cform").serialize());` to ` $.post('process.php', $("#cform").serialize(), function () { $('#cdialog').dialog('close');});`? I think it could be a timing issue. Oh, and remove the `$(this).dialog('close');` right after.

Comment: just did it. it didn't change anything. no errors, but no result as well

Comment: Did you try printing the $_POST variables to the screen **before** passing them to an array.  Just keep walking it backwards until you hit the entry point to the server. Since you **know** Apache is receiving the data in the logs, the problem must be there.  That brings me back to the output question.  Where are your POST variables?  Are you just assuming the data made it to the server because of the 200 response code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having a timing issue. Please change your code from

```
"Save": function() {
            $.post('process.php', $("#cform").serialize());
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
```

to reflect the following

```
"Save": function() {
            $.post('process.php', $("#cform").serialize(), function () {
                  $('#cdialog').dialog('close');
            });

        }
```

Comment: I just tried this. Everything works exactly the same as before and still doesn't process data.

Comment: I know this might be a ridiculous question, but did you clear your browser cache and then try it?

Comment: no, I didn't. I cleared it right now and tried. Everything is the same :( Can it be something with server configuration. Data is sent to php page, but it looks like it's just not running at all. Even when I try to print out a straight number or anything else, let alone $_POST parameters

Comment: Are you attempting to get a response from the server after the $.post() event?

Comment: no, I just need to save data to database and close the dialog. Nothing else